# Dart generated code produces error

Tags: dart, dart2js

Dart 1.20.1

Firefox 49 running on Ubuntu

I've got a Dart web app. When I run the generated JS in Firefox I get this error:

```
H.createRuntimeType is not a function
```

The line in question is:

```
 C.Type_KeyboardEvent_EaM = H.createRuntimeType("KeyboardEvent");
```

Is this something I'm doing or a bug in dart2js?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing what you were doing but it could be a bug.

Comment: You can try to set strong-mode and test the application in dartium with checked mode activated, you will probably get a better error message

Comment: What is the variable `H` set to?  It may not be the type you were expecting. 
 Also friendly suggestion to revise your variable naming strategy.  Variables named `C` or `H` break multiple Airbnb style guide rules : https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#naming--descriptive